Why does dir iis:\appname\workerprocesses have an incorrect result?
On my Windows Server 2019 VM, I used this to check on the worker process:
C:\users\rpresser> ipmo webadministration
c:\users\rpresser> dir iis:\myappPoolName\workerprocesses
Process  State      Handles  Start Time
Id
-------- -----      -------  ----------
4728     Running

This is incorrect. Process 4728 was previously a worker process for this app pool but has been terminated. I tried restart-webapppool and even iisreset and both of those started up new worker processes for my app pool but the dir output continues to refer to process 4728.

Are you able to get the correct worker process information via IISAdministration? https://learn.microsoft.com/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets#iisadministration-overview

Did you start a new powershell session? Perhaps the information is update/populated when the IIS psdrive is loaded? I'd try to force an import of the WebAdministration module and/or try a new powershell session.

@DougMaurer -- a new powershell session provided the correct workerprocess PID, but after recycling the app pool again the new powershell session had the same defect.

@LexLi Yes, the IISAdministration module provided the correct process, but recycling the app pool had the same effect: after the recycle, the old process was still returned.

You skipped over the reimport the module. As I said, the IIS provider isn't even created until the module is loaded. Perhaps a simple Import-Module WebAdministration -Force would refresh it. Please let us know.

@DougMaurer No, reimporting did not work. https://pastebin.com/knK0TKUY

Even removing the iis psdrive and recreating it doesn't refresh the workerprocess PID. I'd recommend sticking to this to reliably get the PID in an existing session
$pid = powershell.exe -noprofile -command "Import-Module WebAdministration;dir IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPool\WorkerProcesses\"

This will start a temporary powershell session and get you the accurate info.

This worked perfectly and I've added it to my personal wiki of vital Powershell snippets.
